# How to remove duplicates in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
print(df)

   Product  Color   Weight  
0     A      Red     13.01
1     A      Red     13.04
2     A      Red     13.10
3     A      Red     13.11
```

I want to remove the duplicates and save only the product with the max() of weight.

```
print(df)

   Product  Color   Weight  
0     A      Red     13.11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `groupby` with `.max`

```
#if you don't care about color remove it from the groupby clause.
#df.groupby(['Product'])['Weight'].max().reset_index()
df1 = df.groupby(['Product','Color'])['Weight'].max().reset_index()

print(df1)

  Product Color  Weight
0       A   Red   13.11
```

Comment: or `df.sort_values('Weight').drop_duplicates(['Product', 'Color'], keep='last')`

Comment: @ansev i did think of this, but I thought the goupby would be more performant

Comment: @ansev Given a dataframe of 1000000 rows with 6 products, 4 color options, and random weight from 5-14: `drop_duplicates` performance = `197 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` and `groupby` performance = `108 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`.

Comment: yes, perhaps the number of groups has to be very large for the option with drop_duplicates to be better :) @Trenton McKinney